# Android - Actionbar not transparent

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, transparent

I am trying to achieve a transparent action bar background effect although strangely it is not working. 
The activity I want to do this to is called "UnitActivity" and here is the xml for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/

</LinearLayout>
```

In my styles.xml

```
    <style name="mangoTheme.UnitActivityActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

in my themes.xml

```
  <style name="mangoTheme.UnitActivityTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mangoTheme.UnitActivityActionBarStyle</item>
  </style>
```

in my manifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".UnitActivity"
    android:label="Unit Selection"
    android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
    android:theme="@style/mangoTheme.UnitActivityTheme">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
<activity
```

The following is the 9 patch file that I am using i.e. "@drawable/transparent"

[image]

NOTE::
I have also tried to write a drawable shape and use that as the background for the action bar which has the following code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#00FFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

I'm just getting grey background color for my action bar... you'd think it would be orange due my background of activity_unit.xml . I must be missing something small at this point :S

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED:**

Turns out I was putting the android:windowActionBarOverlay setting in the wrong place (in the action bar style resource as appose to the theme resource)

Corrected themes.xml

```
 <style name="mangoTheme.UnitActivityTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mangoTheme.UnitActivityActionBarStyle</item>
 </style>
```

Corrected styles.xml

```
<style name="mangoTheme.UnitActivityActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/transparent</item>
</style>
```